# Modify parent component state with key value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a child component in react, I would like to modify the parent component by calling on a function and giving both the key and value. Ideally it would go something like this

```
var FirstView = React.createClass({

handleStateChange: function(key, value) {
    this.setState({
        key: value
    });
}.

render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            <SecondView onStateChange={this.handleStateChange} />
        </div>
    )
}
});

var SecondView = React.createClass({

handleClick: function() {
    this.props.onStateChange('theParent', 'isNowChanged');
},

render: function() {
    return (
        <div onClick={this.handleClick}>Stack Overflow</div>
    );
}
})
```

I'm not entirely sure whether this is the best way to go about this but I would like to pass in a key and a value like above. Unfortunately react doesn't want to play ball and the state of the parent doesn't seem to change. Is there a sensible way to go about this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your handleStateChange in FirstView, you have the following:

```
handleStateChange: function(key, value) {
    this.setState({
         key: value
     });
}.
```

The dictionary passed to `setState` uses the literal `key` rather than the variable `key` passed into the `handleStateChange` function.  Try the following instead:

```
handleStateChange: function(key, value) {
    newState = [];
    newState[key] = value;
    this.setState(newState);
},
```